# Error: Array to string conversion at some profile pages

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I'm looping trough an array when viewing the userprofile:

```
 <?php foreach(unserialize($contact->search_data) as $searchData): ?>
      <li><?= $searchData; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But at some userprofile-pages I'm getting this error: 
**Array to string conversion**

This is the data from a working userprofile:

```
a:2:{s:8:"zip_code";s:6:"3829BE";s:8:"distance";s:2:"15";}
```

Its result:

3829BE

15

This is the data from an userprofile with the error:

```
a:3:{s:12:"Specialiteit";a:1:{i:0;s:18:"Fit worden/blijven";}s:8:"zip_code";s:6:"4731TP";s:8:"distance";s:2:"20";}
```

How to catch this error?

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?php if($contact->search_data): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach(unserialize($contact->search_data) as $searchData): ?>
      <li><?php 
      if(is_array($searchData)){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($searchData as $searchDatas):
          echo '<li>';
        echo $searchDatas;
        echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
        echo'</ul>';
      }else{
      echo $searchData; } ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php else: ?><i>Geen</i><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot echo an array. Use `print_r()`. Then you will get to know how to access the elements present inside that.

```
<li><?php print_r($searchData) ?></li>
```

Comment: .... I didn't see the array inside the array.. It's not my own code but I have to fix it. You're my hero, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your serialized data, the value of array key 'Specialiteit' is an array instead of string, that's why you cannot simply echo it out.

You may edit your code as below:

```
foreach($arr as $searchData): 
    echo '<li>';
    if( gettype($searchData) == 'array' )
        print_r($searchData);
    if( gettype($searchData) == 'string' )
        echo $searchData;
    echo '</li>';
endforeach;
```

Wish this help.